# Positioning spans inside divs

Tags: html, css, css-position

This is the current output of my code,

[image]

Here I want to position the minus icon to top left like this (I edited the following image using paint) ,

[image]

I have included my code below.Here I tried to set the position of the minus span to absolute and It going to the corner of the top.And I don't want it to happen.Is there any way to do this?, I really appreciate your help.I'm trying to do for whole day.

```
    <div class="left-bar-sm">
        <div class="left-bar-sm-header">
           Quantity (0)        
        </div>      
        
        <div class="left-bar-sm-body">
           <div class="left-bar-sm-nested">

             <span>Samaposha</span>     
             <br>
             <span>2 x Rs 28.00 = Rs 56.00</span>
             <span style="float: right;"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i> <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span>
           </div>      
     </div>
```

```
.left-bar-sm-header {
  
  background-color: #333333;
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #595E57;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.left-bar-sm-body {

  height: 450px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #595E57;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.left-bar-sm-nested {

  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #333333;
  border: 1px solid #595E57;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Try `position:absolute;right:10px;top:10px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the text and right side icons in two divs.
Then using `flex` modify the layout to show left and right side.

```css
.left-bar-sm-header {
  
  background-color: #333333;
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #595E57;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.left-bar-sm-body {

  height: 450px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #595E57;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.left-bar-sm-nested {

  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #333333;
  border: 1px solid #595E57;
  display:flex;
}

.right {
    margin-left: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px;
 }
 
 .left {
     padding: 20px;
     flex: 1;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 
 
 
 <div class="left-bar-sm">
        <div class="left-bar-sm-header">
           Quantity (0)        
        </div>      
        
        <div class="left-bar-sm-body">
           <div class="left-bar-sm-nested">

             <div class="left">
               <span>Samaposha</span>     
               <br>
               <span>2 x Rs 28.00 = Rs 56.00</span>
             </div>
             <div class="right"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i> <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
           </div>      
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this Case you can use CSS [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I have slightly changed your HTML.

Try this:

```css
.left-bar-sm {
  background: #252525;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}


.left-bar-sm-header {
  background-color: #333333;
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #595E57;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.left-bar-sm-body {
  height: 450px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #595E57;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.left-bar-sm-nested {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #333333;
  border: 1px solid #595E57;
  padding: 20px;
}

.left-bar-sm-nested > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-bar-sm-nested > div span {
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="left-bar-sm">
    <div class="left-bar-sm-header">
      Quantity (0)        
    </div>      

    <div class="left-bar-sm-body">
      <div class="left-bar-sm-nested">
        <div>
          <span>Samaposha</span>
          <span style="float: right;"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i><span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>2 x Rs 28.00 = Rs 56.00</span>
          <span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
```